# How can I update all application programmatically

Tags: android

How can I update all application programmatically ?

I want create update manager. List all updates and offers to user to update. After clicking, program will update the application.

How can I update application on the android device ?

Answer (score 2):

Download your file from the update server (can be any and use any suitable protocol). Then open it with vnd.android.package-archive:

```
Intent reinstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
reinstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
reinstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile("MyGreatApplication.apk"),
    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(reinstall);
```

This will launch the installer. Be sure you always use the same keystore and key to sign the applications, otherwise an old app can only be overwritten if the user uninstalls the existing version manually.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I update all application programmatically ?

You can't.

> I want create update manager.

This is the responsibility of the "market" app, such as the Play Store client, the Amazon AppStore for Android client, etc.

> List all updates and offers to user to update.

You do not know what the updates are, let alone have the ability to actually perform the updates.

Answer (score 1):

**If you mean Google Play updates**

There is no way to do this using the public SDK. The Google Play application already handles this for you, and Google has not provided an API to hook into or control this behavior.

**If you mean updates to side loaded apps, both yours and others'**

This is sort of possible. You will need to check the version of each application on the device that you wish to update, and have a server somewhere that can tell you the latest version. If the server says a newer version is available, then download the new version's apk to the shared storage on the device, and use an Intent to launch the installer. This cannot be a silent install, and the user will have to manually agree to every update. Additionally, the update apk must be signed with the same key as the old one, and must have the same package name.